# How to signal threads to stop in c# in any one has exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

Suppose that there are 5 threads, T1, T2, T3, T4 and T5 and 5 of them are currently running. My requirement is to stop all 4 threads in case any one of the 5 threads has any exceptions. How can this be achieved. I am using c# 4.0

Comment: can you put some code here?,

Comment: create a bool flag that is accessible to all threads(class variable)..If there's an exception set that flag..All other thread's checking that flag would stop accordingly

Comment: also have a look at [Cancellation Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx)

Comment: Can you have a Singleton class (or static class) that has a flag "Crasched"? The flag should be set in some catch statement by one of the a the thread that has excpetion. The other threads should then poll the flag on a regular basis. Or you could have a "ThreadFactoryClass" that you call to create your threads. When creating a thread, it should put it in a list of crated threads. When one of your threads crashes you call a "StopAllThreads" method on the "ThreadFactoryClass". The method would go through the list an d call Abort on all threads.

Comment: Wouldn't an event be more appropriate? Call the event in the `catch` statement and have that event cancel all threads.

Comment: @Anirudh You should post an answer with the relavent parts from that link - it will help the OP greatly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved by using CancellationTokens. CancellationTokenSource can be shared between your threads.

Here is an example with Tasks, but you can use Threads\ThreadPool

```
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (1 == 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread1 in progress...");
                    if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread1 exiting...");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, cts.Token);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (1 == 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread2 in progress...");
                    if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread2 exiting...");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, cts.Token);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Thread3 in progress...");
                if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread3 exiting...");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, cts.Token);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread5 in progress...");
                int y = 0;
                int x = 1 / y;
            }
            catch 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread5 requesting cancellation...");
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }, cts.Token);
```

and check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx) link which has quite a few CalcellationTokenSource examples (including shared CancellationCancellationTokenSources):

EDIT:
I should probably mention that instead of "breaking" the loop when calcellation is requested, you could just call ThrowIfCancellationRequested method of the Token. The outcome will be different though - the task will not "run to completion", it will be in "Cancelled" state. You need to consider this when adding task continuations.